# Efficiently monitor an int value

Tags: java, swing

*I changed the code to a much more detailed version so you can get a better idea of my problem.*

I need to "watch" an integer value and immediately respond to when it changes. So far the best way I've found is using a thread in an infinite loop.

The following is a vastly simplified portion of my project. To summarize, notificationValue is set to 1 by a click of a button within my Bubble class. I need the applet to be able to monitor this notificationValue and respond whenever it changes.

Here is my applet:

```
public class MyApplet extends JApplet
{
    Bubble myBubble = new Bubble();
    public void run()
    {
        new Thread(
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    if(myBubble.getNotificationValue() == 1) {
                        /* here I would respond to when the
                        notification is of type 1 */
                        myBubble.resetNotificationValue;
                    }
                    else if(myBubble.getNotificationValue() == 2) {
                        /* here I would respond to when the
                        notification is of type 2 */
                        myBubble.resetNotificationValue;
                    }
                    else if(myBubble.getNotificationValue() != 2) {
                        /* if it is any other number other
                        than 0 */
                        myBubble.resetNotificationValue;
                    }

                    // don't do anything if it is 0
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

And here is my class:

```
public class Bubble extends JPanel
{
    public JButton bubbleButton;

    public int notificationValue = 0;

    public int getNotificationValue()
    {
        return notificationValue;
    }
    public void resetNotificationValue()
    {
        notificationValue = 0;
    }

    protected void bubbleButtonClicked(int buttonIndex)
    {
        notificationValue = buttonIndex;
    }

    public Bubble()
    {
        bubbleButton = new JButton();
        bubbleButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                bubbleButtonClicked(1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But obviously that keeps the CPU up at 100% and isn't efficient at all. What would be a better way to do this? (Assume I can't change any of the methods responsible for changing the integer.)

Comment: Usually you would use a lock with a pulse to notify of the change so waiting threads will awake, but this would require an object to lock on and ability to modify the setter.  But it sounds like you cannot inject functionality into the setter?

Comment: However you solve that logic issue in your thread - don't forget that accessing _any_ property of a realized Swing component _must_ happen on the EDT

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> immediately respond to when it changes

How "immediate" does that need to be exactly? Adding a `Thread.sleep(10)` in your while loop would probably bring down your CPU load to near zero.

> What would be a better way to do this? (Assume I can't change any of the methods responsible for changing the integer.)

A better way would be not to expose fields directly. A great example for the benefits of encapsulation - having a setter method would make it trivial to implement the observer pattern.

Comment: I already tried the Thread.sleep(10) and it still stayed up very high. In my project, the integer I need to monitor is encapsulated in a JPanel, and I use getter/setter methods to modify it. I just cannot do it that way because of the way my project is written. I'll try to modify my original post so you can get a better idea.

Answer (score 7):

If that int happens to be a property of a JavaBean, you could use a [PropertyChangeListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html).

However, I suspect that if you need to monitor some integer for a value change you've got a design problem. It'd be better to make sure that integer can only be changed through some method and make sure that method handles the required logic based on the old and new values.

Answer (score 2):

You could use wait/notify. You could use an ExecutorService. A lot depend on whether you can change the code where the integer is set.

Comment: I cannot. If you want to take a look, I completely changed the code example I gave so you can better visualize why I have to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `Thread.sleep(1);` to save CPU.

Answer (score 0):

You can check value of your variable time to time to save CPU. Or use pattern [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Could you encapsulate the integer in another class, wrap with a setter and getter and add a notification (via an Observer)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't change the code which actually sets the integer there isn't much you can do. That being said, if you call Thread.yield() at the end of each pass the impact the thread has on the performance of other applications will be minimal.